# How to turn off and turn default notification sound and vibrations in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to turn off and turn on the default notification sound and vibration that is triggered when I receive a notification on my mobile. I am trying to achieve a certain functionality before which I turn off the defaults and after whose completion I would restore the defaults.

Currently I tried setting the *STREAM_NOTIFICATION* volume to zero and restoring it upon receiving the notification, but it does not work intermittently in some cases.

Is this possible using the *Notification* class? I am interested in turning off and turning on the *default notification sound and vibrate pattern only*.

Explanation with code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There is one very simple solution for it Create one activity for app setting and in your app in which one check box(toggle button) for mute and unmute notification and on button click

```
getApp().getPreferences().setIsNotitficationMute(isChecked);
```

and while you are creating notification i.e. in firebase add these code.

```
if (app.getPreferences().getIsNotitficationMute()) {
            notificationSound = null;
} else {
     notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
}
```